# Magento 1 Text Editor stripping code

Tags: magento-1.9, html

On the privacy policy page there is a link in the text (List of cookies we collect) which moves you down to the cookies table. I made some cosmetic changes to this page in my Admin and noticed that the link no longer works. On closer inspection I noticed the code

```
<h2><a name="list"></a>List of cookies we collect</h2>
```

is stripped down to

```
<h2>List of cookies we collect</h2>
```

in my Admin. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Anchor `<a>` does not support name attribute
second in your case anchor tag does not have any value or or href

Please provide and try again.
Hope this will help your concern

Comment: I have found if you use the id attribute instead of name then it works.

Comment: `<a>` tag does not support name attribute. so if this answer solved your concern then mark as accepted.